# How to use a central bib file in Overleaf?

Tags: bibtex, overleaf

I'm using Overleaf and I have exported a bib file from another project. The problem is that on the other/new project, it refuses to cite (it puts a question mark).

Im using `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}`.

Comment: Have you checked out https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Using_bibliographies_on_Overleaf ?

Comment: Hello there! Tom from Overleaf Support Team here. Overleaf treats the linked files as an internal one for compilation (there is really no distiction) so this should work, and in fact, many users to exactly this. You can reach me on Overleaf support email address and we can see what's going on there. Then if it's something worth sharing with others, I will make an answer here.